# SpringBootにて何が足りない？のかわからない

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

SpringBootにて"Hello World"を表示させるチュートリアル的なものを作成しているのですが、下記一つ目の画像のエラーが出力されます。
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'を追加したり、リフレッシュ後再度ビルドをしましたが特に変わらず。
何が足りないのかわからず教えて頂きたいです。

**試験環境**
Vscode
Mac M1
Java ver '17'
springframework-boot ver '3.0.5'

**現時点でのエラー内容**
[image: エラー内容]

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
[image: エラー内容]
[image: ファイル階層]

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.example.chat.app.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, world!";    
    }
}
```

build実行後コンソール

```
test@test chat % ./gradlew build

> Task :test
2023-04-11T22:53:34.241+09:00  INFO 4832 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-11T22:53:34.242+09:00  INFO 4832 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Comment: プロジェクト構成自体に問題はなさそうに見えます(コンソールで `./gradlew build` を実行してみてそちらでエラーが出なければ問題ないと確証できます/エラーが出るならエラーメッセージを本文に追記してみてください)。 [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084130/4506703) にあるように、"Reload Project" を試してみると VSCode 上のエラーは解消しないでしょうか。

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 
コメントして頂きありがとうございます。
build実行は問題なく成功しましたが、エラーは変わりませんでした。（内容は本文にて追記）
また提供してくださった、"Reload Project" を試みましたが特段変わった事はありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode で Spring Boot アプリケーション開発を行うための、公式に推奨されているプラグインは次のページからリンクされているものです:

- [Spring Boot support in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot)

検索してみたところ、質問文中にある `compiler.err.doesnt.exist` というコードのエラーは上記に含まれない [`Java Language Support by George Fraser`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac) というプラグインが発するようです([言及リンク](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/956#issuecomment-503834068))。
もしこちらをインストールされているのであればアンインストールしてみると解消しないでしょうか。

---

(追記)

`./gradlew build` コマンドが正常に終了するということは、依存関係に問題は無いです。
なので、今回の問題はおそらくVSCodeの設定に原因があるということになります。

[Clean the workspace directory](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#clean-the-workspace-directory) を試してみるとどうでしょうか。
コマンドパレットから次のコマンドを実行することになります:

- `Java: Clean the Java Language Server Workspace`

  - (その後 `Restart and delete` を選択)

([参考リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50821279/4506703))

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。
上記プラグインを外してみたところいくつかのエラーは消えました！
ですが、まだ残っているエラーもあります。
依存関係に問題があると思い確認をしてみましたが、build.gradleにはspring-boot-starter-web等は記載があるのでどこに問題があるかわかりません。
この場合はバージョン番号が正しく指定されているかを確認しほうが宜しいのでしょうか？？
因みに『Reload Project』やビルドは問題なくできます。